# How can i create a stair step/curve?

Tags: matlab, plot, curve

How can I plot a stair curve/step in matlab? I think it should exist a special command to do this. See picture

[stair Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWh7Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about [stairs](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html)?

```
X = linspace(0,4*pi,40);
Y = sin(X);

figure
stairs(Y, '-.or')
```

[image: from MATLAB documentation]

Comment: it is not that what I want...see my screenshot. my input are the red dots (points) with this points I want to create such stairs.....

Comment: X = linspace(0,4*pi,20);
Y = sin(X);

figure
stairs(Y, '-.or')